# How to write a code through which I can remove the image textures attached to Alpha of Principled BSDF of all materials?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

When I import models from online, they come with an Alpha map which makes the whole object translucent looking and when I remove the image textures attached to Alpha map of all materials, it fixes the issue. So, I am looking for a code which will help me a ton to remove the image textures attached to Alpha of Principled BSDF of all materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
```python
import bpy
                            
                            
def remove_alpha_image(object):
    '''
    Remove alpha image texture node.
    
    object (bpy.types.Object) - The object to take material from.
    '''
    if object.material_slots:
        for slot in object.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                node_tree = slot.material.node_tree

                for node in node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED' and node.inputs['Alpha'].is_linked:
                        image_node =  node.inputs['Alpha'].links[0].from_node
                        node_tree.nodes.remove(image_node)
                        
        
remove_alpha_image(bpy.context.object)
````